# Geoserver Optimization: 64 bit vs 32 bit + JAI?

Tags: geoserver, optimization, jai

Since as per my knowledge jai does not support 64 bit, what would be more efficient:

a   Oracle Corporation: 1.7.0_79 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)

**Vs**

Oracle Corporation: 1.7.0_79 (Java HotSpot(TM) 32-Bit Server VM) + Native JAI ?

Comment: Mainly vectors or rasters (aerial or satellite photos) as source data?

Comment: mainly for WMS source is postgres (postgres)

Comment: Native JAI is not avail on win 64 but it is on linux 64.

That said, I would not base my decision on that, native JAI will disappear at a certain point anyway.